# GridView update from Button Click event crashes

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Am facing Array out of exception for the gridview after populating it on ButtonClick event. The same source works just fine when it's triggered from page load. Couldn't find a similar post on stackoverflow. Please advise. Thanks.

**Code:**

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.Cells[0].Attributes["width"] = "30px";
    e.Row.Cells[1].Attributes["width"] = "40px";   -> CRASHES AT INDEX 1
    e.Row.Cells[2].Attributes["width"] = "40px";
    e.Row.Cells[3].Attributes["width"] = "50px";
    e.Row.Cells[4].Attributes["width"] = "50px";
    e.Row.Cells[5].Attributes["width"] = "100px";
    e.Row.Cells[5].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
}

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="4"
    ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Horizontal" Width="100%" ShowHeader="true" 
    EmptyDataText="No Records found.!" 
    RowStyle-Wrap="true" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="5"
    OnPageIndexChanging="gridView_PageIndexChanging"
    OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"         
    style="table-layout:fixed; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left: 0px;" >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be checking to see what type of row it is.  I'm checking for DataRow, but you may want to only do this for Header.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[0].Attributes["width"] = "30px";
        e.Row.Cells[1].Attributes["width"] = "40px";   -> CRASHES AT INDEX 1
        e.Row.Cells[2].Attributes["width"] = "40px";
        e.Row.Cells[3].Attributes["width"] = "50px";
        e.Row.Cells[4].Attributes["width"] = "50px";
        e.Row.Cells[5].Attributes["width"] = "100px";
        e.Row.Cells[5].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
    }
}
```